# How to draw a box at the bottom of the video using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

From the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox) it's pretty straight forward how to create a box at the top with the `y=0`

```
drawbox=x=10:y=0:w=200:h=60:color=red@0.5
```

But how can I draw the box at the bottom?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can reference both the height of the input (`ih`), and the height of the box (`h`). This allows more flexible placement; especially if your inputs vary in size.

To place the box directly on the bottom:

[image: drawbox on bottom]

```
y=ih-h
```

To place the box 10 pixels above the bottom:

[image: drawbox 10 px above bottom]

```
y=ih-h-10
```

See the [FFmpeg drawbox video filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox) for more options.

Comment: I needed `thickness=fill` too.